# What's the difference between downloading xml file using xml.load(url) and downloading the file first, save it and then load it?

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, linq-to-xml, download

and thank you for taking your time to look at my question, I know if there's any kind of performance advantange if instead of using XDocument.Load(Url), I download the file first and then read from it.

For your examples you can use VB.NET or C#, it's all the same for me.

Comment: There is no `XDocument.Load(Uri)`... See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load(v=vs.110).aspx for overloads

Comment: IT DOESN'T SAY URI IT SAYS URL AND THAT MEANS URL

Comment: Where did you get the Uri from?

Comment: @ReedCopsey I _think_ user3044096 is meaning `XDocument.Load(string)`, and user3044096 no need to ALLCAPS SHOUT...

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I meant, I don't see what the problem is here, it's more than clear to me.

Comment: @user3044096 Have you tried streaming versus downloading the XML and tested your assumptions? Or do you mean loading a `string` in memory and using `XDocument.Parse()`? There's a few ways to do this :)

Comment: I'm on it now, but I want to know what's the best way to do it, I have a VPS server with a super fast connection to internet, so I was thinking that it was probably better for me if I download the file first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, downloading the file first and saving it will likely be slower than just using `XDocument.Load(string)`.  The `Load` method which accepts a string will stream the contents directly into the `XDocument` reader, which eliminates extra overhead in the save/read calls.  Internally, the `Load(string)` method creates a `Stream` and downloads the file, reading from the `Stream` directly.

However, if the XML document you're loading is static, and you're calling this multiple times, it could (potentially) make sense to cache it locally to avoid the network traffic.